# Error in autowiring inside Aspects

Tags: java, spring-aop

I have some error during the invocation of a bean inside an Aspect, and I also would like to have some suggestions about initialization of beans inside an aspect class.

1. I am trying to invoke a bean [2] inside my aspects class [1], but in the end I get the following error [4]. It seems that the @Autowired parameter didn't initialize the bean. My configuration file is in [3]. What am I doing wrong?
2. I want that the bean will be invoked one time during initialization. So, even the `map` function is called multiple times, the bean is already initialized. 
   Another solution is, I want (I don't know if it is possible), that the bean will be initialized when the pointcut `map` or `reduce` is invoked by the first time.
   Are these requests possible to do?

Thanks,

[1] My aspect class

```
@Aspect
@Configurable
@Component
public class MapReduceAspects {
  @Autowired
  MedusaDigests digests;

  @Before("execution(* map(..))")
  public void mymap(JoinPoint joinPoint) {
    System.out.println("My Map Execution: " + joinPoint.getArgs() + ":" + joinPoint.getTarget());
    Object[] obj = joinPoint.getArgs();

    if (obj.length > 0) {
        byte[] key = convertToBytes(obj[0]);
        byte[] value = convertToBytes(obj[1]);

        digests.updateDigest(key, value);
    }
}

@Before("execution(* reduce(..))")
public void myreduce(JoinPoint joinPoint) { System.out.println("My Reduce Execution");
   Object[] obj = joinPoint.getArgs();

   if (obj.length > 0) {
       byte[] key = convertToBytes(obj[0]);
       byte[] value = convertToBytes(obj[1]);

       digests.updateDigest(key, value);
    }
  }
}
```

[1] My aspect

```
@Component
public class MedusaDigests {
    private final String MD5 = "MD5";
    private MessageDigest mda = null;

    public MedusaDigests() {
        try {
            mda = MessageDigest.getInstance(MD5);
        } catch (NoSuchAlgorithmException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
           e.printStackTrace();
       }
    }

    public void updateDigest(byte[] key, byte[] value) {
      mda.update(key);
      mda.update(value);
    }
}
```

[3] My beans-aspects.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
   xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
   xmlns:aop="http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop"
   xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
   xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop/spring-aop-3.2.xsd http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.2.xsd http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.2.xsd">

<aop:aspectj-autoproxy proxy-target-class="true"/>
<!--<aop:include name="mapreduceAspect"/>-->
<!--<aop:include name="jobClient"/>-->
<!--</aop:aspectj-autoproxy>-->
<!--<context:load-time-weaver/>-->
<context:component-scan base-package="org.apache.hadoop.mapred"/>

<bean id="mapreduceAspect" class="org.apache.hadoop.mapred.aspects.MapReduceAspects" factory-method="aspectOf" autowire="byType" />
<bean id="medusaDigests" class="org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MedusaDigests"/>
```

[4] the error that I get

```
WARNING: job_local138234703_0001
java.lang.Exception: java.lang.NullPointerException at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.LocalJobRunner$Job.runTasks(LocalJobRunner.java:462)
at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.LocalJobRunner$Job.run(LocalJobRunner.java:522)
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.aspects.MapReduceAspects.mymap(MapReduceAspects.java:50)
at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.examples.DummyWordCount$Map.map(DummyWordCount.java:32)
at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.examples.DummyWordCount$Map.map(DummyWordCount.java:1)
at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Mapper.run(Mapper.java:146)
at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask.runNewMapper(MapTask.java:787)
at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask.run(MapTask.java:341)
at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.LocalJobRunner$Job$MapTaskRunnable.run(LocalJobRunner.java:243)
at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

Answer (score 0):

In the first you don't need declare your beans at the xml configuration and using annotation like this:

```
<bean id="medusaDigests" class="org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MedusaDigests"/>
@Component
public class MedusaDigests {...}
```

You must declare bean only in one place, for example you can remove tags:

```
<bean id="mapreduceAspect" class="org.apache.hadoop.mapred.aspects.MapReduceAspects" factory-method="aspectOf" autowire="byType" />
<bean id="medusaDigests" class="org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MedusaDigests"/>
```

Secondly, tag

```
<context:component-scan base-package="org.apache.hadoop.mapred"/>
```

does not scan Autowired annotation, if also you want scan @Autowired annotation  you can choose one of two variants:

declare in xml configuration

```
<bean class="org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor"/>
```

or

declare in xml configuration

```
<context:annotation-config/>
```